# Java. How to create a JPanel with resizable text area and fixed buttons area?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

How to get a layout like this in Java?

|-----------------------------------------------|
| Fixed size "top" panel with labels
|----------------------------------------------|
|  Resizable text area
|  It expands to most of the parent
|  panel (except the fixed areas)
|
|----------------------------------------------|
|  fixed JTextArea(always 2 lines
|  full frame width)
|----------------------------------------------|
|                 RightCenteredButtons
|----------------------------------------------|

I tried the code below, but I cant get it to work. Elements are floating, text areas are clashing. I can't figure out how to expand text area to all available frame, except fixed areas.

```
 JPanel top = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT , 10, 10));
 top.add(label1);
  ....
 top.add(labelLast);
 add(top);
 JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea();
 add(area1);
 JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea();
 add(area2);
 JPanel bottom= new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT , 10, 10));
 bottom.add(button1);
  ....
 bottom.add(buttonLast);
 add(bottom);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `BorderLayout` on the main panel.

1. Create a panel and add it to the `PAGE_START`. Then set the layout of the panel and add components to the panel.
2. Create a JScrollPane with a JTextArea and add it to the `CENTER`
3. Create a JScrollPane with a JTextArea and add it to the `PAGE_END`

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

> fixed JTextArea(always 2 lines full frame width)

and when you create the JTextArea you use:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(2, 20);
```

to specify the fixed number of lines.